# Repeat until user presses enter

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

I want to have a loop, that repeats until the user presses enter.

I tried with `while(getchar != '\n'){}` but this waitet on a input every single time. Right now i dont know how to do this.

```
do {
        clear;//system("cls");
        printf("\nPress [enter] to continue");
        printf(".");
        Sleep(500);
        printf(".");//should give a output with press enter to continue... and wait after every point.
        Sleep(500);
        printf(".");
        Sleep(500);
    }while(getchar() != '\n');
```

Comment: `stdin` is usually line buffered.  _Nothing_ is available to `getchar()` until `'\n'` is entered - even the first call.  Perhaps a non-standard function?

Comment: Only the getchar() part needs to be in a loop.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/423643/204883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code is from [kbhit for linux](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/63166-kbhit-linux.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int kbhit(void)
{
  struct termios oldt, newt;
  int ch;
  int oldf;

  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
  newt = oldt;
  newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
  oldf = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf | O_NONBLOCK);

  ch = getchar();

  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf);

  if(ch != EOF)
  {
    ungetc(ch, stdin);
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  while(!kbhit())
    puts("Press a key!");
  printf("You pressed '%c'!\n", getchar());
  return 0;
}
```